# Show Python FTP file upload messages

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have a remote FTP server where I want to upload new firmware images. When using the Linux `ftp` client I can do this using `put <somefile>` the server then responds with status messages like:

```
ftp> put TS252P005.bin flash
local: TS252P005.bin remote: flash
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 40929
226-File Transfer Complete. Starting Operation:
Checking file integrity...
Updating firmware...
Result: Success
Rebooting...
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
38563840 bytes sent in 6.71 secs (5.4779 MB/s)
ftp>
```

Now I can upload the file using Python as well using ftplib:

```
fw_path = ....
ip = ....
user = ...
pw = ....
with open(fw_path, "rb") as f:
    with ftplib.FTP(ip) as ftp:
        ftp.login(user=user, passwd=pw)
        ftp.storbinary("stor flash", f)
```

But I can't see a way for me to get the status messages that I can see using the `ftp` utility. This is important for me because I need to check that the update actually succeeded.

How can I get this output in my Python program? I'm also willing to use a different library if ftplib can't do it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the response programatically, check the result of [`FTP.storbinary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary):

```
print(ftp.storbinary("STOR flash", f))
```

---

Though as your server actually closes the connection before even sending a complete response, the `FTP.storbinary` throws an exception.

If you want to read the partial response, you will have to re-implement what the `FTP.storbinary` does. Like

```
ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')
with ftp.transfercmd("STOR flash") as conn:
    while 1:
        buf = f.read(8192)
        if not buf:
            break
        conn.sendall(buf)
line = ftp.getline()
print(line)
if line[3:4] == '-':
    code = line[:3]
    while 1:
        nextline = self.getline()
        print(nextline)
        if nextline[:3] == code and nextline[3:4] != '-':
            break
```

---

If you want to check the response manually, enable logging using [`FTP.set_debuglevel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.set_debuglevel).

Comment: Wow thx works like a char!